# Detect or identify a framework in php (Yii or CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, yii

I have a quick question.

I have an existing project in php. Now, i am trying to set up locally.  I am checking the way to find out which framework they have used.

Can any one guide me how to detect framework in that existing project? Is there any way?

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you have the source code, you can check the folders present, there should be some files that tell what framework had been used

Comment: @Swellar Thanks for the reply. How do i detect YII framework in source code?

Comment: Not really sure, as I don't use Yii, but you can look in the documentation and look for similar codes or files used

Comment: Any particular reason why you can't just ask which framework they used?

Comment: for Yii you could check for comments in base class where they have comments containing //@license http://www.yiiframework.com/license/

Comment: @SudhirBastakoti Can you provide a single line ? so that i can search using that sentence in source code

Comment: In case of Yii, you could search for `namespace yii\web`

Comment: @SudhirBastakoti Found out that its not yii

Comment: @SudhirBastakoti How about zend?

Comment: Well there are many ways, for Zend you could search for `Zend\Http` or `Zend_Application` for CodeIgniter you could search for either `CI_Controller` or `CI_VERSION`

Comment: @SudhirBastakoti Thanks a lot. Here is common-model.php which i have inside models folder. https://paste.ofcode.org/EM2cfaVKFTef3UzZ23kPTz. Hope this might help you to figure out

Comment: @Jacky I highly doubt that the code you shared of, is from any popular open source framework. The way its coded, commented looks like its some custom built framework.

Answer (score 3):

You can use chrome extension "wappalyzer".This extension shows which frameworks are used.

Comment: This extension is available for firefox and safari too.